# Unlist a list - common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a function that returns something like this:

```
'(1 4 2 8)
```

and I want to apply the following type of functions to it:

```
(name &rest)
```

for example:

```
(max '(1 4 2 8))
```

produces an error, but:

```
(max 1 4 2 8)
```

does not.
so I have to "unlist" that list. How may I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `apply` is the traditional way:

```
(apply 'max '(1 2 3 4))
; => 4
```

Comment: Oh dear I knew that. Oops.

Comment: @SpenserTruex no harm done. The term 'unlist' is a good one so this should maybe be kept here but closed as a duplicate

Comment: I probably need to learn not to make stackoverflow questions at 2am

Comment: However, in this case, `(reduce 'max '(1 2 3 4))` would be better.  It's dangerous to apply functions to arbitrary arglists, since there are implementation limits on how long arglists can be.